# Calculating posterior distribution

Tags: statistics, bayesian

[image]

From the above, I follow the argument and see that the posterior distribution of $\theta$ is proportional to a pdf which has density of a beta random variable. But i do not understand why because the posterior is proportional to a distribution, implies it is exactly that distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bayesian inference one often finds the posterior distribution as *proportional*
to the product of the prior distribution and likelihood function. In case the
prior and likelihood are 'conjugate' (mathematically compatible), it is
possible to ignore constants.

Specifically, if the prior is Beta and the
Likelihood is Binomial, the posterior will be Beta. As in your
example, all that is necessary is to find the appropriate power of $\theta$
and of $(1-\theta).$

Once you know that the 'kernel' of the posterior (PDF without constant)
is of the form $\theta^{1-\alpha_n}(1-\theta)^{1 - \beta_n},$ then you know
that the posterior distribution is $\mathsf{Beta}(\alpha_n,\, \beta_n)$. If for some reason, you need to know the 'constant of integration' $K$ you can
find it as $1/K = \int_0^1 \theta^{1-\alpha_n}(1-\theta)^{1 - \beta_n}\,d\theta,$
so that $\int_0^1 K \theta^{1-\alpha_n}(1-\theta)^{1 - \beta_n}\,d\theta = 1.$
Of course, $K = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}.$
In short, there really can be *only one PDF* that has kernel 
$\theta^{1-\alpha_n}(1-\theta)^{1 - \beta_n},$ for $\alpha_n, \beta_n > 0.$

The conjugate distribution pair Poisson-gamma is used similarly for Bayesian
inference on the Poisson rate parameter $\lambda.$